# Akka HTTP WebSocket client equivalent of this node.js

Tags: websocket, akka-http

I have some user documentation that expresses how to use a websocket with this node snippet:

```
var socket = io(“HOST:PORT”);
socket.on('request-server', function() {
  socket.emit('server-type', 'red')
});
```

What would the equivalent client code be in Akka HTTP?

I have derived the following from the example in the Akka documentation. It isn't quite what I'd like to write, because

- I think I need to connect and wait for the `request-server` event before sending any events & I don't know how to do that
- I don't know how to format the `TextMessages` in the `Source` to be equivalent to `socket.emit('server-type', 'red').

It only prints "closed"

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
import system.dispatcher

val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[Message] {
  case message: TextMessage.Strict => println(message.text)
  case z => println(z)
}

val outgoing = Source(List(TextMessage("'server-type': 'red'")))

val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(
  WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:3000/socket.io"))

val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
outgoing
  .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both)
  .run()

val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
  if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
    Future.successful(Done)
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
  }
}

connected.onComplete(println)
closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
```

What is the Akka client equivalent to the given socket.io code?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is getting closed immediately after sending message "outgoing".

Check out Half-Closed Websockets here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html#half-closed-websockets